# Haskell - replace strings in list with values from a map

Tags: haskell, dictionary

i have this problem:
i want to have a list of strings representing math expression, and a map of arguments to replace the variables.
so if my list is like ["x","+","y","-","5"] and arguments are [("x","5"),("y","4")]
the function should return ["5","+","4","-","5"]

i have this function to find key from map (from the Learn you a haskell book)

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v
findKey key [] = Nothing
findKey key ((k,v): xs) = 
        if key == k
           then Just v
           else findKey key xs
```

and then my function to replace the variables with values

```
takeValuesFromMap (x:str) m result
        |x == [] = result
        |findKey x m == Nothing = takeValuesFromMap str m (result++[x])
        |otherwise = takeValuesFromMap str m result++[fromJust (findKey x m)]
```

if no match in the map, we pass the regular string. Otherwise we pass to the result the value staying next to the key that matches.

but in the end when i call

```
takeValuesFromMap ["x","+","y","-","5"] (Map.fromList [("x","5"),("y","4")]) []
```

it says

```
Solver.hs:63:48:
Couldn't match expected type `[([Char], [Char])]'
            with actual type `Map.Map [Char] [Char]'
In the return type of a call of `Map.fromList'
In the second argument of `takeValuesFromMap', namely
  `(Map.fromList [("x", "5"), ("y", "4")])'
In the expression:
  takeValuesFromMap
    ["x", "+", "y", "-", ....]
    (Map.fromList [("x", "5"), ("y", "4")])
    []
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `takeValuesFromMap xs m = [v | x <- xs, let v = maybe x id $ findKey x m]`

Comment: if you remove Map.fromList in the call to takeValuesFromMap, it will work

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a different track here, and suggest that you *don't* solve this problem.  The reason is that the list `["x","+","y","-","5"]` is a very poor representation of the algebraic expression `x + y - 5`. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but a better approach would represent the expression as an **abstract syntax tree**, using an algebraic datatype.

So for example, we could use the following type to represent the expressions:

```
data Expr a = Variable String 
            | Literal a 
            | Plus Expr Expr 
            | Minus Expr Expr
```

Given this type, your example goes like this:

```
example :: Expr Integer
example = Minus (Plus (Var "x") (Var "y")) (Literal 5)
```

It's easy to write a function that evaluates expressions of this type, given a `Map` from variable names to values:

```
-- | Evaluate an expression, reading variable's values from the given environment
-- (the Map argument).  Returns Nothing if any of the variables is undefined.
eval :: Num a => Expr a -> Map String a -> Maybe a
eval (Variable v) env = Map.lookup v env
eval (Literal x) _ = Just x

eval (Plus x y) env = 
    -- If this is confusing, read up on the Maybe monad in Learn You a Haskell
    do x' <- eval x env
       y' <- eval y env
       return (x + y)

eval (Minus x y) env = 
    do x' <- eval x env
       y' <- eval y env
       return (x - y)
```

More complex, but well worth learning, is then to write a parser that takes a string and turns it into an `Expr`.  If you're reading *Learn You A Haskell*, you may want to first get more comfortable with monads and applicatives.  But when you're ready to take that step, there's a number of pages on the web with calculator parser examples:

- http://meta-meta.blogspot.com/2007/10/simple-infix-calculator-in-haskell.html
- http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_xuff3BkASMOzBr0hKVKLuSnU4UIinKx
- http://haskelladdict.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/a-nice-little-calculator-implemented-in-haskell-and-parsec/

Though you may want to read this part of *Real World Haskell* first:

- http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html

Answer (score 0):

In `findKey` you require an association list, but you are actually using a Map. So, one way to fix it woulde be to remove `Map.fromList`.

Another point: Never replace pattern matching with equality checks! So please write:

```
| [] <-  x = ...
| Nothing <- findKey x m = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the type of `Map.fromList`. Am I right in assuming that you take `Map` from `Data.Map`? If so:

```
:t Data.Map.fromList
Data.Map.fromList :: Ord k => [(k, a)] -> Map k a
```

So, this function returns Map, but your `findKey` actuall wants a list of tuples `[([Char],[Char])]`. You have got two choices now:

1. Use a function from `Data.Map` instead of your `findKey` to lookup a key.
2. Use another function to build your list.